# How to write query for mongodb? I need to set parameter in array

Tags: mongodb

I have this doc:

```
{
    '_id': 123456,
    'name': 'myName',
    'state':[{'user_id':1,user_state:1},{'user_id':11,user_state:2}]
}
```

I need to set one more filed ,'is_active':1, in state array object, where "_id" == 123456, and user_id == 11.

As a result it should look like this:

```
 {
     '_id': 123456,
     'name': 'myName',
     'state': [{'user_id':1,user_state:1},
               {'user_id':11,user_state:2,'is_active':1}]
}
```

But I am stuck with query:

```
{_id: new ObjectID(123456)}, {$set:{'state':???}}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
db.colection_name.update({_id: ObjectId("123456"), "state.user_id": 11}, { $set:{ "state.$.is_active" : 1 }})
```

Comment: will try now. thanks!

Comment: worked.thanks. marked your answer.

Comment: Happy to help :)